# Print html pages mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mozilla

I am trying to print an HTML table with a lot of content inside. But I haven't had any luck with Google Chrome, so I decided to use Mozilla Firefox, and for some reason, it's work breaking page inside the table. So the question is how to call print preview in Firefox with Javascript (*there is no print preview if i call `window.print();`*).

[image: Like this...]

I see mozilla set this header and footer automatically but is there any way to set custom header on print? Or maybe disable it by default everytime users click print button.

Comment: i have tried this one myself there is no print preview in ff , ie , safari, but there is in chrome and opera

Comment: the headers only can be hidden by the end user (not customizable, you should made your document on printable format), the print preview is a feature implemented by the browser, only Chrome and Opera have it, if you need show a preview crossbrowsing you need to do by yourself

Comment: @kamus how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this..

Place your printable part inside a div with an id like this:

```
<div id="printableArea">
  <h1>Print me</h1>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a div!" />
```

Now let's create a really simple javascript:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

 window.print();

 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

}

or check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/35vAN/
in this fiddle you can see there is a option for header and footer

Comment: Properties of Firefox in different from chrome,pop up arrives but in different format,  I think in Firefox in that pop up u have to go for PDF creator and click advanced , where u can change the defaults

Comment: nope, well i think pdf creator mean for "save file to pdf". But no preview at all, i need to go to settings bar and press print to get a preview. So sad

Comment: pdf creator wil print, but its in pdf format, But preview in firefox, i am not sure..

Comment: It's good, but with front-end framework like Angular, React, Vue ..etc. It will break all of events of each component. All you guys can't do with this method even though this is a good trick. Thanks @AnoopB.K